# Visual Studio Project Favicon

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2012, razor

After migrating a template over to my visual studio web application, I can't seem to get the favicon to work. The icon is 16x16, is named favicon.ico, and is placed in the Content/images directory of my project. I've made references to other images with this path that work fine. Any ideas?

```
 <link runat="server" rel="icon" href="../Content/images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

Comment: Try putting the file at the root of the project.

Comment: The problem was fixed when I inserted the favicon reference code into the layout in the Shared folder rather than index.cshtml itself.

Answer (score 4):

Well if it doesn't work, there's only one option - your path is wrong.

Try this:

```
<link runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/Content/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Also, the type is "image/x-icon"...

Comment: Protip: _always_ use `~` as much as you can. (also good catch)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally (a hangover from the first use of favicon.ico) it should be placed at the root of the website.

The image/x-icon is for IE.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

For the following browsers it is best to still be in the root...
Google Chrome   Internet Explorer   Safari

For the following browsers it is optional to be in the root...
Firefox     Opera

Answer (score 0):

Clearing your cache may fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `?v=2` to your `href`
for example: `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>`

Some browsers try to  cache previous versions of the "favicon.ico".This addition overrides that functionality  if they didn't exist. I ran in to this using Live Server in VSCode editor, it works!